# Does using ReaderWriterLockSlim cause a memory barrier?

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking

If I am using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to acquire read/write locks, do I need to make my variables `volatile` or use `Interlocked.Increment`?

For example, would the code in the `Add` method below work fine, or does it need enhancement?

```
public class AppendableList<T> { // semi-immutable; supports appending only
    private T[] data = new T[16];
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim rwLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public T this[int index] {
        get {
            rwLock.EnterReadLock();
            try { return data[index]; } finally { rwLock.ExitReadLock(); }
        }
    }
    public void Add(T item) {
        rwLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try {
            if (Count == data.Length)
                reAllocateArray(); // upgrades to write lock
            data[Count++] = item; // do I need to use Interlocked here?
        } finally { rwLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock(); }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to write a light-weight, fast and simple list that allows multiple threads to access its data concurrently (sort of producer-consumer buffer). I have edited the code above removing the simplifications I used before, so the issue should be clearer now. It seems to me that this code is thread-safe, but I am not sure whether all threads will see the updated value of `Count` right after exiting the upgradeable lock.

**EDIT 2**: The "Write" lock here is used to indicate writing to the *array reference*, not the array elements. I'm assuming this is sufficient (since the data itself is immutable). I guess that I need to use Interlocked when incrementing `Count`. Is that true?

Comment: [Jeffrey Richter's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163599.aspx) provides some detailed advice on ReaderWriterLock.

Comment: This one was more informative regarding ReaderWriterLockSlim:
http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/02/07/IntroducingTheNewReaderWriterLockSlimInOrcas.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would fully *expect* the write-lock to function as a memory barrier (within the write-lock, in particular), but I can't prove it off-hand.

Whether you need the complexity of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` depends on the context; `Interlocked`, `volatile`, `lock` or `[MethodImpl]` might each do the job far more simply. You mainly need `ReaderWriterLock[Slim]` if you have lots of readers and few writers.

However, the `get` is not currently protected by the lock; you'll need to us an explicit property implementation and take out a read lock yourself if you ever need multiple operations to be spanned by the write-lock (without readers seeing intermediate values).

As an aside, the `Count++` usage would probably be more familiar to people.

You should also use `try`/`finally` to ensure you release the lock on exception.

To avoid the issue of taking write then read locks, perhaps:

```
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim rwLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private int count;
    public int Count {
        get {
            rwLock.EnterReadLock();
            int tmp = count;
            rwLock.ExitReadLock();
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    public void Add(object x) {
        rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try {
            // do some processing
            count++;
        } finally {
            rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
```

---

Updated re your edit;

That looks pretty solid. A `List<T>` would be my recommendation (over a `T[]` array), since it will do all the doubling etc internally, saving you lots of code. Since only one thread can update `Count` at a time, there is no need for `Interlocked`, and this property saves the need for a lock when reading `Count`, as long as you're fine for callers to get the old `Count` while another thread is adding rows (rather than being blocked).

Comment: You might also consider marking count volatile (as opposed to a full read lock), depending on what you're actually using it for. If you need to be 100% sure the write is 100% finished before seeing the new value, use a read lock. If it doesn't matter, volatile should provide adequate protection.

Comment: On the other hand, if your property is something more complex than, for instance, an int, you will need a read lock; volatile won't prevent you from seeing partially-updated complex structures.

Comment: Note: for a collection like you've implied here, a read lock is probably the way to go; but you should evaluate case-by-case how much protection you really need.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Eric. I edited my question to clarify it. Previously I had simplified the example to be consice, thus removed try/finally and irrelevant code. I've rewritten the example to clarify my question.

Comment: I am assuming that the code is thread-safe, because elements are immutable, and the count is only incremented when more data is available.

Comment: But now I'm not sure! If the JIT changes the order of instructions, then a thread might get wrong data (e.g. null) if it sees the updated Count before the assignment to the array element takes place. In this case even volatile wouldn't save me. So should I use Interlocked instead?

Comment: Thanks. So one final question: Is there a way to make sure that other threads will always see the updated Count after exiting the lock?

Comment: I think that should already happen. If not, well, `volatile` or including the `get` in the read-lock should do it.

Comment: Actually, no, there still may be a race in your edited code; if two threads are adding, they can read Count over each-other. I would use an exclusive lock for Add (to keep it simple but provably right), probably just via Monitor (lock).

Comment: But how? Since only one thread is allowed to EnterUpgradeableReadLock at any given time, this case should never happen, right?

Comment: @Hosam: I believe you are right, you shouldn't have any issues with Count updates stepping on each other. However, you could still end up with the updated Count being read via get before the new element is put in the array.

Comment: ...If that's an issue, I'd use data[Count] = item; Count++; and make Count volatile, which should prevent the first line from getting reordered to after the second line, and also ensure that the new value of Count is immediately visible to other threads.

Comment: @Eric: Even if a thread reads the updated Count before the new element is assigned, the read lock in the indexer will not be granted until the upgradeable lock exits, so I believe this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: ... Using volatile also makes much sense, but if ExitUpgradeableLock() causes a memory barrier then I guess I don't need it, and that's my last question: does it cause a memory barrier?

Comment: Valid point on the indexer. As for the memory barrier... I don't know for sure. However, marking Count volatile would also ensure that other threads always reread the value and not potentially miss an update -- if that is a concern -- which I don't think a memory barrier on the write would address.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/MP_issues.mspx) it does, for a very in-depth overview of the various memory barrier cases, check that document out, you can find the non-fence'd lock's if you want also.

And please, **DO NOT USE VOLITILE IT IS LESS AND LESS EFFECTIVE THESE DAYS!!**

> All of the standard Windows locking
>   mechanisms (spin locks, mutexes,
>   kernel events, and resources managed
>   by the executive resource package)
>   protect against processor reordering
>   by inserting memory barriers where
>   required in executable code.
>
> A memory barrier is a processor
>   instruction that preserves the
>   ordering of read and/or write
>   operations from the perspective of any
>   other processor. Memory barriers
>   include processor instructions with
>   acquire, release, and fence semantics.
>   These semantics describe the order in
>   which results of an operation become
>   visible.
>
> - Acquire semantics mean that the results of the operation are visible
>     before the results of any operation
>     that appears after it in code.
> - Release semantics mean that the results of the operation are visible
>     after the results of any operation
>     that appears before it in code.
> - Fence semantics combine acquire and release semantics. The results of an
>     operation with fence semantics are
>     visible before those of any operation
>     that appears after it in code and
>     after those of any operation that
>     appears before it.